# Munin apache plugin bad response

Tags: apache-2.2, munin

All my apache plugins returns the same value :

`/usr/share/munin/plugins# munin-run apache_volume
volume443.value U`

Here is my config in /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node

`[apache_*]
env.ports 443`

Some have an idea where is the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The apache scripts are not compatible with ssl. You have to use modified version on : 
http://munin-monitoring.org/attachment/wiki/PluginCat/apache_volume
http://munin-monitoring.org/attachment/wiki/PluginCat/apache_accesses
http://munin-monitoring.org/attachment/wiki/PluginCat/apachessl_processes

Be sure to have the perl libraries  LWP::UserAgent and Crypt::SSLeay installed

Modify also /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node :

`[apache_*]

env.ports 443

env.url https://localhost:443/server-status?auto`

It works fine after that ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that! Only the links to the scripts are not longer valid. But the changes to the scripts are easy. See also at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up apache to provide status information?
in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf`
you need something like

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
ExtendedStatus On
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost ip6-localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried also with your conf to test. Same result. when I go to the /server-status page, it works normally. </code>munin-run apache_volume
volume443.value U
order:/usr/share/munin/plugins# a2enmod status
Module status already enabled
</code>

Answer (score 0):

***At first: See also my EDIT below! May be you don't must change the scripts!***

The answer of "hotips" is right (+1 for that), but only the links are not longer valid. But you can do the changes in the three scripts by self. It's easy. After installing the perl packages LWP::UserAgent and Crypt::SSLeay (like it was described by "hotips") edit each script and change following lines:

```
...
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30,
           agent => sprintf("munin/%s (libwww-perl/%s)", $Munin::Common::Defaults::MUNIN_VERSION, $LWP::VERSION));
...
...
    my $response = $ua->request(HTTP::Request->new('GET',$url));
...
```

into:

```
...
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 30,
            verify_hostname => 0,
            agent => sprintf("munin/%s (libwww-perl/%s)", $Munin::Common::Defaults::MUNIN_VERSION, $LWP::VERSION));
...
...
        my $response = $ua->get($url);
...
```

After that don't forget to add the configuration entries `env.ports 443` and `env.url https://localhost:443/server-status?auto` to `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node` (also described by "hotips")

**EDIT**

Arrghhh! Find out an interesting thing. May be you don't need to change the scripts! In my case after installing the two perl packages and add the configuration entries the scripts working very well with SSL!